# How to create a squeeze page for attached files under Drupal 7?

Tags: 7, forms, files

I have a content type set up in my Drupal 7 site which has an attached file. As it currently stands, this file can be freely downloaded without requiring a user account.

I do not want to require users to create an account on this site, but I would like to set up a 'squeeze page' for the newsletter/mailing list. That is, when someone decides to download the file, I'd like to present a dialog or screen a bit like this:

> Enter your email here to sign up for our email newsletter:
>
> [***_*__*_*_**] [Sign up and Download]
>
> OR
>
> [No thanks, I'd just like the file]

I found two modules which would have worked if I were using Drupal 6 - Webform Protected Downloads and Squeeze Page, but no equivalents for Drupal 7. I was considering using the Custom Formatters module and a light box/dialog of some sort to jury rig it, but then I'd still need to code something to save the emails out again.

Is there a more elegant solution out there for this requirement? I am capable of coding new modules myself if that's the only option, but the less new code I need to write for this the better. Perhaps there might a module or combination of modules which comes close, which I could then tweak or modify?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of modules out there and I assume you found them, your particular implementation will affect which suits you, but for D6 or D7 take a look at the [Comparison of file download gateway and tracking modules](https://drupal.org/node/1613392).

I have found each of these to be too specific and limiting in some or other way and have resorted to using webform and some custom coding.